# Filtro de ventana móvil en C

Tags: c, array

Estoy probando un código en C para esta consigna:
Realice una función que implemente un filtro de ventana móvil de 10 valores sobre un vector de muestras, cuyo prototipo de fución debe ser:

```
void filtroVentana10(uint16_t * vectorIn, uint16_t * vectorOut, uint32_t longitudVectorIn);
```

¿Por qué en el código debe ir el operador `%` en vez del operador `/` para calcular pos en el siguiente código?

```
#define VENTANA_SIZE 10

void filtroVentana10EnC(uint16_t * vectorIn, uint16_t * vectorOut, uint32_t longitudVectorIn)
{
    int suma_parcial = 0;
    int i = 0;
    uint32_t pos = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < longitudVectorIn; i++) {
        suma_parcial = 0;
        int x = i;

        for (x = i; x < i + VENTANA_SIZE; x++) {
            pos = x % longitudVectorIn;
            suma_parcial += vectorIn[pos];
        }
        vectorOut[i]=suma_parcial/VENTANA_SIZE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Lo siento pero por mas que leo la pregunta no entiendo cuál es tu duda. Por favor edita la pregunta para aclarar tu duda

Answer (score 0):

El operador `%` te da el resto de la división.

Es un "truco" muy típico para ir incrementando un índice hasta llegar a un valor máximo y que después vuelva a empezar por cero, ya que el resto de dividir entre `N` siempre es un número entre 0 y N-1.

Si usas como `N` la longitud de un vector, te aseguras de que el resultado siempre esté entre los valores permitidos (de 0 a la longitud del vector menos uno).